# Why does my MacBook Air keep restarting because of a problem?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

On an admin account on my MacBook Air mid-2013 I have tried repairing the disk and disk permissions, tried doing it from recovery partition and have even reinstalled the OS. This is the diagnostic log that keeps coming up. Is there anything else to do in order to fix it?

```
Anonymous UUID:       981B271B-F7EF-2F26-C3CD-24525AB21793

Tue Dec 30 10:47:58 2014

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801e21f12a): "Double fault at 0xffffff801e147f94, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff8128597f88, CR3: 0x0000000020e29000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0\n" "RAX: 0xffffff81285980c0, RBX: 0xffffff7f9ec75270, RCX: 0xffffff81285980c0, RDX: 0xffffff801e5edb30\n" "RSP: 0xffffff8128597f90, RBP: 0xffffff81285980b0, RSI: 0xffffff81285980e0, RDI: 0xffffff7f9ec75270\n" "R8:  0x000000000000000a, R9:  0xffffff801e5edb30, R10: 0x0000000000000001, R11: 0xffffff803d53ca78\n" "R12: 0xffffff8031624400, R13: 0xffffff801e910688, R14: 0x0000000000000001, R15: 0x0000000000000001\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff801e147f94, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff811f604e90 : 0xffffff801e13a811 
0xffffff811f604f10 : 0xffffff801e21f12a 
0xffffff811f605070 : 0xffffff801e23ad0f 
0xffffff81285980b0 : 0xffffff801e5ed8f2 
0xffffff81285980d0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6f512 
0xffffff81285985f0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6cfc0 
0xffffff8128598620 : 0xffffff801e6d8008 
0xffffff8128598680 : 0xffffff7f9ec013cf 
0xffffff8128598700 : 0xffffff7f9efa07a1 
0xffffff8128598730 : 0xffffff7f9efa04c8 
0xffffff8128598760 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a87a 
0xffffff81285987b0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6d2eb 
0xffffff8128598850 : 0xffffff7f9ec6aa1f 
0xffffff8128598930 : 0xffffff801e6d8008 
0xffffff8128598990 : 0xffffff7f9ec6b20d 
0xffffff8128598a30 : 0xffffff7f9ec24942 
0xffffff8128598ac0 : 0xffffff7f9ec0194b 
0xffffff8128598b30 : 0xffffff7f9ec018d5 
0xffffff8128598b80 : 0xffffff7f9efa0d7a 
0xffffff8128598bc0 : 0xffffff7f9ef98ba1 
0xffffff8128598bf0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a87a 
0xffffff8128598c40 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a614 
0xffffff8128598cd0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6cc50 
0xffffff8128598db0 : 0xffffff801e6d8008 
0xffffff8128598e10 : 0xffffff7f9ec013cf 
0xffffff8128598e90 : 0xffffff7f9efa07a1 
0xffffff8128598ec0 : 0xffffff7f9efa04c8 
0xffffff8128598ef0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a87a 
0xffffff8128598f40 : 0xffffff7f9ec6d2eb 
0xffffff8128598fe0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6aa1f 
0xffffff81285990c0 : 0xffffff801e6d8008 
0xffffff8128599120 : 0xffffff7f9ec6b20d 
0xffffff81285991c0 : 0xffffff7f9ec24942 
0xffffff8128599250 : 0xffffff7f9ec0194b 
0xffffff81285992c0 : 0xffffff7f9ec018d5 
0xffffff8128599310 : 0xffffff7f9efa0d7a 
0xffffff8128599350 : 0xffffff7f9ef98ba1 
0xffffff8128599380 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a87a 
0xffffff81285993d0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a614 
0xffffff8128599460 : 0xffffff7f9ec6cc50 
0xffffff8128599540 : 0xffffff801e6d8008 
0xffffff81285995a0 : 0xffffff7f9ec013cf 
0xffffff8128599620 : 0xffffff7f9efa07a1 
0xffffff8128599650 : 0xffffff7f9efa04c8 
0xffffff8128599680 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a87a 
0xffffff81285996d0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6d2eb 
0xffffff8128599770 : 0xffffff7f9ec6aa1f 
0xffffff8128599850 : 0xffffff801e6d8008 
0xffffff81285998b0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6b20d 
0xffffff8128599950 : 0xffffff7f9ec24942 
0xffffff81285999e0 : 0xffffff7f9ec0194b 
0xffffff8128599a50 : 0xffffff7f9ec018d5 
0xffffff8128599aa0 : 0xffffff7f9efa0d7a 
0xffffff8128599ae0 : 0xffffff7f9ef98ba1 
0xffffff8128599b10 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a87a 
0xffffff8128599b60 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a614 
0xffffff8128599bf0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6cc50 
0xffffff8128599cd0 : 0xffffff801e6d8008 
0xffffff8128599d30 : 0xffffff7f9ec013cf 
0xffffff8128599db0 : 0xffffff7f9efa07a1 
0xffffff8128599de0 : 0xffffff7f9efa04c8 
0xffffff8128599e10 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a87a 
0xffffff8128599e60 : 0xffffff7f9ec6d2eb 
0xffffff8128599f00 : 0xffffff7f9ec6aa1f 
0xffffff8128599fe0 : 0xffffff801e6d8008 
0xffffff812859a040 : 0xffffff7f9ec6b20d 
0xffffff812859a0e0 : 0xffffff7f9ec24942 
0xffffff812859a170 : 0xffffff7f9ec0194b 
0xffffff812859a1e0 : 0xffffff7f9ec018d5 
0xffffff812859a230 : 0xffffff7f9efa0d7a 
0xffffff812859a270 : 0xffffff7f9ef98ba1 
0xffffff812859a2a0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a87a 
0xffffff812859a2f0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a614 
0xffffff812859a380 : 0xffffff7f9ec6cc50 
0xffffff812859a460 : 0xffffff801e6d8008 
0xffffff812859a4c0 : 0xffffff7f9ec013cf 
0xffffff812859a540 : 0xffffff7f9efa07a1 
0xffffff812859a570 : 0xffffff7f9efa04c8 
0xffffff812859a5a0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6a87a 
0xffffff812859a5f0 : 0xffffff7f9ec6d2eb 
    Backtrace continues...
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(705.4.14)[E15E9DC8-410F-3612-8371-E5FECD939E0D]@0xffffff7f9ebf1000->0xffffff7f9ec55fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f9e924000
         com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub(705.4.1)[CB19C93C-FB00-3FF9-B290-D1D70773C76C]@0xffffff7f9ef98000->0xffffff7f9efb2fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(705.4.14)[E15E9DC8-410F-3612-8371-E5FECD939E0D]@0xffffff7f9ebf1000
         ng.uds.netusb.controller(1.59)[2E19F0F2-5AF7-30BD-7C91-70EB5380512E]@0xffffff7f9ec62000->0xffffff7f9ec7ffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(705.4.14)[E15E9DC8-410F-3612-8371-E5FECD939E0D]@0xffffff7f9ebf1000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14B25

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x000000001de00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801e000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801df00000
System model name: MacBookAir6,2 (Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977E5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 42978329925575
last loaded kext at 6943064111: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  175.5 (addr 0xffffff7fa02ac000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 189918610458: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  2.0.45 (addr 0xffffff7fa008e000, size 36864)
loaded kexts:
ng.uds.netusb.controller    1.59
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.1.0d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.12
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.23.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 46.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   901.19.10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  175.5
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.1f2
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 267.0
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 267.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 267.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.4
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   175.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    26.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  260.30
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   700.52
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  26.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    2.0.45
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 2.0.45
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.45
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B16, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.13f15
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.10)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.1f2 15015, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6
```

Comment: are you using parallels ? the ng.uds.netusb.controller  belongs to it.

Comment: nope, no parallels on this machine. I do have taxer though since work with NTFS drives a decent amount

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a USB network adapter? The panic report references the kernel extension "ng.uds.netusb.controller".

If so, either look for an updated software package for the USB network adapter, or uninstall the software.

Comment: I have no idea where its from, I'm assuming from the netgear router? I can't find the extension though.

Comment: Look for the file ng.uds.netusb.controller.kext in /System/Library/Extensions/. If it's there, move it to the trash and then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess just based on what you've posted, I would guess you may be looking at either a hardware incompatibility or hardware failure. First, try booting without any external devices attached. If you still get kernel panics like this, try the Apple Hardware Test suite: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257

Finally, make sure your laptop has good ventilation and is not overheating.

Comment: done all the above before, doesn't matter what is or isn't plugged in, apple test says all good even when everything is plugged in, and isn't overheating at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an SMC reset (http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and see if the issue persists. If it does boot to the recovery partition and just reinstall the OS (http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13871) (This will not affect any of your personal data)

Comment: done both multiple times